# Change the background of a td containing radiobutton in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to achieve this in the below screen shot on the page load I want to be able to select all the system generated heading and so set the background to green. I am able to accomplish this. 
but when the selection is changed for example when a current heading is selected I want the background color to change with the selection as well. I am having problems accomplishing this.

Here is the code behind this .

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Associate Format</th>
            <th>Addressee</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Current Heading</th>
            <th>System Generated Heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let assoc of this.assocService.associateArray; let idx = index" [attr.name]="idx">
            <!--<td style="display:none;">
                {{assoc.assocType}}
            </td>-->
            <td>
                {{assoc.assocTypeName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{assoc.addressee}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{assoc.contactname}}
            </td>
            <td [ngClass]="this.tdindex == idx && this.tdh1Selected || this.heading1Selected ? 'backgroundGreen' : 'backgroundGrey'" [attr.name]="idx"  >
                <input type="radio"  [attr.name]="idx" (change)="onHeading1Select($event,assoc,idx)"  [checked]="this.heading1Selected"  value="{{assoc.heading}}"/>  {{assoc.heading}} 
            </td>
            <td [ngClass]="this.tdindex == idx && thistdh2Selected || this.heading2Selected? 'backgroundGreen' : 'backgroundGrey'"  [attr.name]="idx">
                <input type="radio"  [attr.name]="idx" (change)="onHeading2Select($event,assoc,idx)" [checked]="this.heading2Selected"  value="{{assoc.systemHeading}}"/> {{assoc.systemHeading}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the code behind

```
heading1Selected: boolean = false;
    heading2Selected: boolean = false;

    tdh1Selected: boolean = false;
    tdh2Selected: boolean = false;
    tdindex: number;

 onHeading1Select(event,assoc:any, index: any) {
        debugger;
        let assocObj = assoc;
        for (let a of this.assocService.associateArray) {
            if (a.contactId == assocObj.contactId) {
                a.selectedHeading = assocObj.heading;
                this.tdindex = index;
                this.tdh1Selected = true;
                this.tdh2Selected = false;
                this.heading2Selected = false;
            }
        }

        this.caseSvc.inMemoryCase.associates = this.assocService.associateArray;
    }

    onHeading2Select(event,assoc:any, index: any) {
        debugger;
        let assocObj = assoc;
        let sysHeading: string = assocObj.systemHeading;
        for (let a of this.assocService.associateArray) {
            if (a.contactId == assocObj.contactId) {
                if (sysHeading.includes('cannot') || sysHeading.includes('CANNOT'))
                {
                    a.selectedHeading = assocObj.heading;

                }
                else {
                    a.selectedHeading = assocObj.systemHeading;
                    this.tdindex = index;
                    this.tdh2Selected = true;
                    this.tdh1Selected = false;
                    this.heading1Selected = false;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I know I am very close in solving this issue but something is lacking ... could anyone have any pointers to save me some time

Answer (score 0):

**change the condition as following**

```
<td [ngClass]="assoc.tdindex == idx && (assoc.tdh1Selected || assoc.heading1Selected) ? 'backgroundGreen' : 'backgroundGrey'" [attr.name]="idx"  >
    <input type="radio"  [attr.name]="idx" (change)="onHeading1Select($event,assoc,idx)"  [checked]="assoc.heading1Selected"  value="{{assoc.heading}}"/>  {{assoc.heading}} 
</td>
<td [ngClass]="assoc.tdindex == idx && (assoc.tdh2Selected || assoc.heading2Selected)? 'backgroundGreen' : 'backgroundGrey'"  [attr.name]="idx">
    <input type="radio"  [attr.name]="idx" (change)="onHeading2Select($event,assoc,idx)" [checked]="assoc.heading2Selected"  value="{{assoc.systemHeading}}"/> {{assoc.systemHeading}}
</td>
```

**and inside the functions use `assoc` instead of `this`**

```
assoc.tdindex = index;
assoc.tdh1Selected = true;
assoc.tdh2Selected = false;
assoc.heading2Selected = false;
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RgOdBGvWEVbi4PBuJoMk?p=preview)

***Note: This will fix the problem, but your code has lot of other issues.***